# C: simple HTTP server. Read a local file and download it from browser

Tags: c, http, attachment, send

I'm working on a simple server that have to work with a browser. When I give it some command, it has to reply me with some html code so to reply my answer. For example I can see the list of the files of a folder etc. I can access my server using localhost:port/somecommand
Now I'm working on donwloading a file from the local hard-disk. What I want to do is enter an url like localhost:port/download/filepath and make the browser download it. When I create the reply I put all things html need to understand that there is a file to download, and infact I have the classical pop-up window that ask me to download the file, but what I receive is bigger than the original file located to the hard-disk, and infact the file is corrupted.
Here the code:

This is the html I send back

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue Apr 10 16:23:55 2012
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mypic.jpg
Content-Length: 2574359
                       //empty line here
```

(I followed  [The Content-Disposition Header Field text](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) )

then I read from file and I send back html first and what I read from file then:

```
int file=open(name,O_RDONLY);
void * data=malloc(buf.st_size+1); //buf.st_size is the correct file size
size_t readed=read(file,data,buf.st_size);
send(sd_current, html, DIRSIZE, 0); //html is a string containing what you I showed you 
send(sd_current, data, readed);
```

This result the file I can download using localhost:port/download/filepath to be bigger than original then corrupted, but I can't get rid of why. Can someone help me?

Comment: `send(sd_current, html,DIRSIZE);`  did you intend it to be DIRSIZE or length of html string?

Comment: yeah, trying from a version to another I forgot to change this.. I changed now to strlen(html) and now the file I download is only 2byte bigger!! We are close :D

Comment: OK SOLVED!! thanks all! It was just this fu**ing DIRSIZE :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. is DIRSIZE really the size of the http header? (Since the size should vary, and capitals normally means constant).
2. Is the read successful?
3. How is the file corrupted?
4. Are the line endings on the http header correct? They should be \r\n

EDIT:

If DIRSIZE is not the size of the header, then the rest of the buffer (containing NULLs or junk) will be sent to the other size.

So the other side sees the HTTP header, then starts receiving data - starting with the rest of the `html` buffer, then the contents of the file.

Then depending on the receiver, it either stops at the `Content-Length` header size, or carries on while the stream is still delivering data.

Does that match your result contents: Some junk at the beginning, followed by the expected file contents?

Comment: 1) yes of course I'm not showing here whole code, but DIRSIZE is 8192 and the html header is less then 200 2) read and send have no errors 3) file is corrupted because it's bigger then original so I think there is some junk code somewhere 4) http header should be ok.. I had no \r then I added it but no luck

Comment: EDIT: I added \r better and now size is a bit smaller, near to the file size:
here new code same as before but with this sends

     send(sd_current, html, DIRSIZE, 0);
     send(sd_current, data, buf.st_size, 0);
     char * end ="\r\n";
     send(sd_current, end, strlen(end), 0);

anyway still file corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length: 2574359, 2574359 should be the size of your jpg file, but I see nothing in your code to put that in the html portion. buf.st_size == 2574359 ?

Comment: yes I used stat() to get this size and even the html use this number so buf.st_size == 2574359 (that is the file size). The only thing I noticed is that the resulted file have the same "size on disk" but different "size" looking to their properties.. can this help?
EDIT: now the file is only 2 byte bigger!

Comment: if it is windows, you need to make sure the data read is in "binary" mode and the byte size send() is exactly the same as in the content-length tag. Make sure readed is the same as buf.st_size